# Mantaflow Alembic export for compositing

Tags: rendering, export, fluid-simulation, alembic

I m new in bender and use it for flow simulation, I m trying to export a composition did with mantaflow to get the animation fusion 17.

i only have the domain's cube and not the simulation. Do you know if there is a possibility to save Alembic file of the simulation itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to bake the simulation, but once you've done that all you need to do is select the Domain and go File>Export>Alembic. Easy as that